# ReactJS + Stripe: trial_period_days not functioning

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

trial_period_days: 7 does not seem to be recognised in my node function. Any idea why this may be the case? Am I missing a variable? When posting to this it causes an integration error...

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
                customer: customer.id,
                items: [{ price: "price_1KZ3nTGxUje7SlyIDUfIXkr3" }],
                payment_settings: {
                  payment_method_options: {
                    card: {
                      request_three_d_secure: "any",
                    },
                  },
                  payment_method_types: ["card"],
                  save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
                },
                trial_period_days: 7,
                expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
              });
```

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: IntegrationError: Missing value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string.

Comment: This is not an error coming from `stripe.subscriptions.create()`.

Comment: More on this - it seems that it creates the subscription etc in Stripe all good, but does not create the user as a Firebase user... in my functions log - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'client_secret')

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Subscription with a trial or a 100% coupon, there’s no Invoice to pay immediately. Therefore, there’s no PaymentIntent, and no client_secret. That’s why your PaymentIntent confirmation failed. Instead, the Subscription creates a SetupIntent to collect a Payment Method to use in the future. You can access the client secret of the SetupIntent via `pending_setup_intent.client_secret` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent) (you will need to expand `pending_setup_intent` property when creating the Subscription). Then, you will need to [confirm SetupIntent on the frontend](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_setup). To better understand how SetupIntents work you can follow this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web.

Comment: thanks - but I dont fully understand - if I change stripe.subscriptions.create to stripe.setupIntents.create then I still get the same error

Comment: You don't need to change the API call. You need to access a different property of the created Subscription: `pending_setup_intent.client_secret`. That's the client secret you need to be sending to your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Paul, I was just running into this same issue, because I was coming from C#, and it was just a regular field in the object to create the session. In TypeScript though, looks like the field is hidden under "subscription_data" in the session create options. So something like this should work:

```js
let checkoutSession = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    customer: customer.id, 
    success_url:"https://mycompany.com", 
    line_items: [{price: priceId}], 
    allow_promotion_codes: true,
    mode: "subscription",
    subscription_data: {trial_period_days: 7} //this is the field.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Also here is the link to the API docs for more info: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create.

Comment: I just realized this is not an exact answer, but close enough, haha.